# How to create grep command in java as linux grep command

Tags: java, linux

I want a simple Java application which will work like linux `grep` command, also take input from pipeline.

Thanks

Comment: Simple application and `grep` contradict each other

Comment: @adarshr, only if you implement the regular expression engine yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1st U have to check for command line `args`

if avail more than `2 arguments` then, 1st one is radix and 2nd one is file name
read file line by line, match the radix string, and print it

if command line is only `1 argument` then you should check for `System.in`
which comes from pipeline
read line by line and check that single arg String as radix and print it.